# Channel entries category tag only showing last category

Tags: channel-entries, categories

Within my `exp:channel:entries` tag, I am using the `categories` tag pair to show the categories that the entry is in. However, it is only showing the last category that the entry is in:

```
{exp:channel:entries}
    <h3><a href="{url_title_path='photos'}">{title}</a></h3><br />
    {image_upload}
        <img src="{path}_thumbs/{filename}.{extension}" />
    {/image_upload}
    <a href="{url_title_path='photos/printing'}">Print this photo</a><br />
    Categories: {categories backspace="2"}{category_name}, {/categories}<br />
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This is the same on both the development and live sites.

There are a number of categories in the database (a couple of hundred), but each entry is only in around 2 or 3 categories. The correct categories are all selected when editing the entry in the admin panel.

Comment: What happens when you add the `channel` parameter in the `exp:channel:entries` tag with the correct channel name?

Comment: @Siebird - no difference

Comment: It's a good idea to always specify channel - otherwise EE will pull from all channels in the system. 

What URL is this page appearing at? What happens if you pull off the backspace parameter on the categories loop? Anything different if you strip out everything to just title and category?

Comment: Tried all those things, no joy unfortunately. The problem appears at different URLs on the development and live sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've discovered the cause:

The channel entries and categories are added through a web service, and it turns out I missed the `exp_category_field_data` table.

Without anything in this table, only the last category was showing. I've updated the web service to add the categories to this table, and it's working correctly now.

Comment: Grr I hate EE sometimes -- they make it so difficult to import data cleanly.

Comment: If you don't need category fields, your web service can ignore the `exp_category_field_data`. Just make sure your `{exp:channel:entries}` tag has `disable="category_fields"` and all of the categories will show up.